# PowerShell Form GUI - Object

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer, powershell-cmdlet

I’m kind of new in the PowerShell world and I’m trying to create a basic GUI for my team.

I created a form with couple of buttons and I want that every button will basically run quite a simple command.

**For example**:

[ Unlock User ]        [ User Name Text Box ]

- Unlock User = Button
- User Name Text Box = a text box that I will put the name in.

I want the “Unlock User” button to take the input text from the text box and use it as the identity of the user.

Unlock-Adaccount -identity $TextBox.text

My issue is that the $TextBox / $TextBox.text
Is a Windows.forms.textbox object.

So:  How can I convert that object to a simple string or AD object?

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-a-custom-input-box?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

As a rule you should really show your code as well as your explanation and error items.

However, your button click event on the form has to have code to grab the string from the text box and that button click event has the code to do what you are after.

```
$buttonUnlock = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'

    $buttonCheck_Click={

        # Get the Current text in $textbox1
        $name = $textbox1.Text

        # Search for this account in the current domain
        $Searcher = [ADSISearcher]"(sAMAccountName=$Name)"
        $Results = $Searcher.FindOne()
```

There are pre-built items like this for you to leverage from many resources. Yet learning to do it from scratch is still a good thing. However, being new and jumping directly into GUI dev, without any background is, well challenging.

The above snip is from the resources below.

> Active Directory User Unlocker [ADSI] (WinForm GUI)
>   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WinForm-Active-Directory-a3771370/file/79019/1/AD-USER-Unlocker.ps1
>
> PowerShell GUI script to unlock an Active Directory user’s account
>   https://github.com/supersysadmin/WindowsPowerShell/blob/master/Scripts/GUI/AD/ADUserUnlock.ps1

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this inside your Button Click event.

`$Identity = ($TextBox.text).ToString().Trim()`

Then use it like:

`Unlock-Adaccount -identity $Identity`